# How do I get the raw script output instead of the query result from an Oracle SQL select in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I need to backup some data as INSERT statements through a Java application. The most straight-forward approach I could find in SQL Developer was running a select with `/*insert*/`.

For example:

```
SELECT /*insert*/ * FROM table_name WHERE col_a = 1 AND col_b = 2;
```

If I run this query as a script (F5) in SQL Developer I get its result just like I need. The problem is I can't find a way to run this query as a script from my Java application and get the DB text output back to the program. I'd like to receive the script output as a String, then print it to a file.

Conventionally I run all my queries with `JdbcTemplate` and `PreparedStatementCreator`, but all methods in `JdbcTemplate` seem to require some sort of row mapping to transfer the query content to an object's attributes.

Comment: Converting the result of the query to `INSERT` statements is something **SQL Developer** does, not the database. You have to code your own logic for converting the `ResultSet` data to `INSERT` statements.

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your answer. I opted to follow your advice and implemented a row mapper that outputs the rows from the result set as insert statements. Not the most elegant solution, i think, but it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out, the `/*insert*/` is a sqldev / sqlcl feature. However, you can include SQLcl into your java code and call these features. Here's a sample that gets the insert statements. Then run them with:

```
sqlcl.setStmt(<SCRIPTOUTPUTHERE>);
sqlcl.run();
```

I wrote a blog post about it here:

http://krisrice.io/2016-11-15-sqlcl-as-library-in-existing-programs/

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE","klrice","klrice");

//#get a DBUtil but won't actually use it in this example
DBUtil util = DBUtil.getInstance(conn);

//#create sqlcl
ScriptExecutor sqlcl = new ScriptExecutor(conn);
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedOutputStream buf = new BufferedOutputStream(bout);
sqlcl.setOut(buf);

//#setup the context
ScriptRunnerContext ctx = new ScriptRunnerContext();

//#set the context
sqlcl.setScriptRunnerContext(ctx);
ctx.setBaseConnection(conn);

//#change the format
sqlcl.setStmt("set sqlformat insert");
sqlcl.run();

//#run the sql
sqlcl.setStmt("select * from user_objects");
sqlcl.run();

String results = bout.toString("UTF8");
System.out.println(results);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Kris, please be sure to explicitly declare attribution when sharing links to your own stuff!

Comment: Sure will be more verbose in future.

Comment: Your answer seems very good. However, I ended up implementing my own "as insert" output generator. I'll accept this answer since the library you pointed out does seem to solve the issue besides offering several other possibilities. Thank you very much.